# Java: Create large number of Callables or distribute iterator result to threads?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I've written an application to manipulate images. My manipulation code should be applied to all images (up to 1 Million per folder) in a folder.

So far, for each image in the folder I create a `Callable` (which is a worker to manipulate the images) and add it to an `ArrayList`. Then I use the `invokeAll` method of a `FixedThreadPool` to parallelize the work.

However, my question is: **Is this good design?** I have some doubts that adding 1 Million elements to the array list first really makes sense. I was thinking of passing an `iterator` (over the files) to all the threads and to let each thread take the next element and process it (with the problem of blocking of course, unfortunately) - but does that make sense?

Comment: Do you have a million cpus?

Comment: I don't work at Google, sorry ;-)

Comment: Me neither.  My intent was to hint at the "common wisdom" that you generally don't want to create more threads than you have cpus.

Comment: Yeah, got it. But I don't really create more threads than cpus. Sorry if I didn't specify that clearly. I only create a million Callables, but the number of threads is at around 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sounds ok even if it is not necessarily very efficient and does not scale very well. An alternative design could be:

- create an `ArrayBlockingQueue<File>` bigger in size than your FixedThreadPool (say twice as big)
- create a `FileVisitor`, let's call it `ImageFileVisitor`, which in the `visitFile` method `puts` the visited file in the queue - that is a blocking call so it will wait until the queue is not full
- create as many `Callable`s as the size of your pool and make each of them `take` from the queue and do what they have to do

Note: the size of the Thread pool should be fairly small. If your image processing is very heavy, use the number of processors for the size, if it is somewhat trivial and most of the time is spent reading/writing files, use a smaller size.

Comment: That sounds very good! I'll try to implement it and get back to you very soon! Thanks!

Comment: @navige Regarding the FileVisitor, the easiest way is to extend SimpleFileVisitor and override `visitFile` (and call `super.visitFile()` at the end of the overriden method).

Comment: :-) Yes! That's what I also just realized!

Answer (score 1):

`FixedThreadPool` uses `LinkedBlockingQueue` of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`:

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }
```

So, its affectively non-blocking, as in you would be able to `offer`/`put` million `Runnable` instances to it, surely this is unnessary usage of memory for holding millions of objects though your `fixedPoolSize` would be comparatively much much smaller say 5/10.

One approach which would directly improve this scenario is to use `FixedThreadPool` with a finite queue size:

```
int nThreads = 10;
int maxQSize = 1000;
ExecutorService service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                          0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                          new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxQSize))
```

With above apporach your `put` call will block on `1000` runnables in `Q`, but as soon as some of them finishes, `put` will continue. By doing `invokeAll`, there would be 10 running threads and max 1000 runnable instances.